# What is the difference between C pointer and Objective C pointer?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I know its a very basic question. Got some memory issues I need to clarify. Here is my doubt:

```
int *p = malloc (50); // will allocate 50 bytes and it is pointed by p.

// Freeing C pointer-->

free(p);
```

Objective-C pointers:

```
ClassAobject *objA = .... // allocated ClassAobject..

// Freeing obj-C pointer--->

objA = nil // Is it enough??? will it release all ivars memory properly..
```

what if the case, If I have some C pointers inside the objective C class? How to handle this in ARC

Comment: If you are using ARC you dont need to release any objects

Comment: No need to assign nil also...?

Comment: If you don't, you need to retain/release objects, much like you did in C. Which do you use?

Comment: ARC = AutoRetainCount -> It counts the references to the object and collects those, who are not being pointed to any more. Meaning -> You HAVE to assign nil or any other reference, so the GC will take out the object you don't need any more. Compare to Java for that.

Comment: @ATaylor maybe you could drop an answer with all details

Comment: ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) doesnt collect references. It is an compiler feature that inserts all the needed retain/release/autorelease calls for you. There is also no GarabageCollector on iOS and the GC in OS X is going to die. @Newbee it is a good idea to assign nil to your pointer, but ARC will do all the memory management even if you don't assign nil. Your Object will receive a release or autorelease message when its scope is finished.

Comment: @ring0 There's a sufficiently detailed answer already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The title doesn't reflect what you're asking. **There's no difference between C pointers and "Objective-C pointers".** Really they're just plain ol' C pointers.

What you're asking for is the difference between their correct usage. If a pointer points to an Objective-C object, then under MRC, you have to do

```
[obj release];
```

to decrease its reference count (which can potentially deallocate it). Under ARC, setting the pointer to `nil` is enough (as in your example).

Comment: what if the case, If I have some C pointers inside the objective C class, I should free it right? when I should do?

Comment: @Newbee In the `- (void)dealloc` method of your class. Also, don't forget to call `[super dealloc];` **at the end.**

Comment: @Newbee you should really read the apple docs or get a book for simple stuff like this. We aren't your personal teachers.

Comment: @H2CO3 If Newbee is using ARC as the last sentence of his/her question suggests, calling `[super dealloc]` is prohibited.

Comment: @Metabble Right. However, I assumed he wanted to learn/know how reference counting works, so I defaulted to the MRC answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'd always default to the answer applicable to the user's current situation and add others if I thought it would be helpful. I didn't take it as them wanting to learn MRC. Regardless, it's still good to specify whether or not advice is for ARC/MRC. We wouldn't want someone to add `[super dealloc]` when they're using ARC and end up asking another question on SO, would we? xD Anyways, +1 for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between "C pointers" and "Objective-C pointers". void* and int* are exactly the same in C and Objective-C.

However, when you use ARC some pointer types are handled specially by ARC. These pointer types are:

```
id
Pointers to Objective-C objects like NSString*
Class
Blocks
```

These are all pointers to various kinds of Objective-C objects that are reference counted. ARC automatically keeps track of how many references to any of these objects exist, and if the last reference is removed, the object itself is deallocated.

If an object is deallocated, ARC automatically removes all the references to objects that it referred to. However, if an object has pointers that are not under ARC control, you have to do whatever you need to do in dealloc.